# Schengen visa extension

Tags: visa, schengen

I am from India and I have applied to a vocational school in Berlin. I have been accepted and invited to an interview which is a part of their admission procedure. Upon my total acceptance, I intend to study there for one year. What visa should I apply for? I am not sure if I should apply for a schengen visa or a national visa. Can I extend the schengen visa once I am accepted? Are schengen visas and student visas the same?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to travel to Germany for study purposes, you have to apply for the appropriate German Visa, related to the purpose of your travel and stay there – studying.

There are 3 (three) types of German Visas for study purposes:

1 - Language Course Visa (Visa for Language Learning) – is the perfect option for those that want or need to learn the German language in Germany.

2 - Student Applicant Visa (Visum Zur Studienbewerbung) – if you want to study in Germany, but are still trying to find the right program or you still haven’t got the confirmation letter from your University.

3 - Student Visa (Visum Zu Studienzwecken) – if you have already been accepted to a German university.

Comment: Where can I find the student applicant visa form ? Or is it the same as schengen student visa ?